How to configure individual LSPs (specifically pylsp) in Neovim using Mason, mason-lspconfig, and lspconfig plugins
When using pylsp with Neovim, I get errors such as E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1 and E741 ambiguous variable name 'l'. Simple formatting errors such as these seem pointless to me and clutter my workspace. How would I go about configuring pylsp to not show these errors?
For reference, my nvim config directory looks like this:
├── lua
│  ├── plugins
│  │  ├── alpha-nvim.lua
│  │  ├── gitsigns.lua
│  │  ├── gruvbox.lua
│  │  ├── harpoon.lua
│  │  ├── lsp-config.lua
│  │  ├── lualine.lua
│  │  ├── simple-plugins.lua
│  │  ├── telescope.lua
│  │  ├── treesitter.lua
│  │  ├── which-key.lua
│  │  └── yazi.lua
│  ├── keymaps.lua
│  └── options.lua
├── init.lua
└── lazy-lock.json

I use lazy.nvim for my plugin manager, and Mason, mason-lspconfig, and lspconfig to install and manage my LSPs. All of my lsp configuration is in the file lsp-config.lua, the contents of which  are as follows:
return {
  {
    "williamboman/mason.nvim",
    config = function()
      require("mason").setup()
    end
  },
  {
    "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim",
    config = function()
      require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
        ensure_installed = {
          "clangd",
          "pylsp",
          "lua_ls",
          "texlab",
        }
      })
    end
  },
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    config = function()
      local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
      lspconfig.clangd.setup({})
      lspconfig.pylsp.setup({})
      lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({})
      lspconfig.texlab.setup({})
    end
  },
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope-ui-select.nvim",
    config = function()
      require("telescope").setup({
        extensions = {
          ["ui-select"] = {
            require("telescope.themes").get_dropdown {
            }
          }
        }
      })
      require("telescope").load_extension("ui-select")
    end
  },
}

This post seems to be very similar to my question, but I don't know where the person is putting this code.
